# My Private key from myetherwallet.com was stolen

Tags: ether

My private key (from myetherwallet.com) was stolen by hackers. Can I change it?

Comment: You can generate a new account. But if your previous was stolen you have to take some measures to ensure the new can be safely generated.

Comment: Just to help others protect themselves, can you edit your question to describe how you think you were hacked?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "change private key, keeping the same account address" - then NO. You should create new account and immedeately take an action to save your assets, controlled by old account (i.e. transfer money from old account to a new one).

If you mean "change stolen password, keeping the same account address" - then YES. You can recreate your keyfile with new password (programmatically). But it is not recommended, because hackers knowing the password, may be already know your private key as well.